# Is it bad to access an inner asynctask in another class?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

In my activity i call this code too access the inner **AsyncTask** which is in another class.

But i would like to know if this is a bad idea.

```
 new SongsLibrary.AsyncTaskData(this, this, this, false).execute();
```

Comment: please use coroutines. because the async task is deprecated in android 11

Comment: @BhanuPrakashPasupula I only target api 28 so android pie

Comment: @BhanuPrakashPasupula just would like to know if this is a bad idea if i access an asynctask which is an inner class in another class.

Comment: yes it is bad design, you can use interfaces as callbacks